# Allocating from previous unallocated id in table?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sqlite

Allocating old id's to new row added in a table.
For example:

```
id | name
1  | n1
2  | n2
3  | n3
4  | n4
```

So if I delete row with id = 2,table will look like

```
id | name
1  | n1
3  | n3
4  | n4
```

Now I add another row,
For this row is it possible that id = 2 is alloted in mysql.
I can make a java program in which I find all missing id's between 1 to (highest id alloted) in table and giving one of those missing id to the new row.

Is it possible to do it in mysql. 
Here 'id' is primary key.

Comment: Do not do that. Let MySQL to handle the auto increment, don't mess with it.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but just out of curiosity: _why_ would you want to re-allocate sequential primary key values?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza  you are right, actually I am writing two table, through which I am generating tree like json structure using java , so I am using those the values of 'id' as index of array(also nodes of the tree) in java so mysql can handle very very large values till 18446744073709551615 of primary key, but  java will not handle it ,I am finding the solution for it. But this question randomly arised in my mind as I just want to know is it possible.

Comment: Use `String` in Java side to store such key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really dont know why you want do that. Instead you should set Primary Key to autonumeric and use same type as your java type.

But here is a solution [SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f4069/6)

```
SELECT @newID := MIN(E1.employeeID) + 1
FROM Employee E1
WHERE not exists ( SELECT E2.employeeID 
                   FROM Employee E2
                   WHERE E2.employeeID = E1.employeeID + 1
                 );

INSERT INTO Employee values (@newID, 'name ' + @newID);
```

This look for each ID if exist ID + 1. If ID + 1 doesnt exist is free to use

So return the smaller (ID + 1)

Answer (score -1):

I don't think so, when anything gets deleted from SQL wrt the primary key the whole tuple gets deleted, if you delete an attribute of a particular tuple it remains null instead of the lower value being inserted there.